# Custom Caret for WinForms TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, caret

I'm developing a custom HyperTerminal like application in a WinForms .Net 2.0 application. I have a  multiline TextBox in a Panel in which you can interact with a hardware device.

My customer wants to have a custom Caret, a filled rectangle the size of one character space instead of the vertical line that is by default.

I know .Net does not provide an option to do this by default, but there must some Windows function to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume a form with a textbox on it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCaret(textBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 10, textBox1.Height);
        ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

These are the list of Native Caret functions provided by Windows you can use them for you application.

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, int hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCaretPos(int x, int y);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool DestroyCaret();

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Refer SharpDevelop, Source Code @ src\Libraries\ICSharpCode.TextEditor\Project\Src\Gui\Caret.cs

Comment: `CreateCaret`'s `hBitmap` parameter should be typed as `IntPtr` and not `int` because it's declared as `HBITMAP` which is a typedef of `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use System.Drawing to draw a custom cursor (bitmap), maybe with a timer to let it blink like another cursor.

Get the current position of the Cursor in pixels and draw a bitmap over that cursor. Can be tricky to find the correct position, but should be doable.

Have a look here for [Owner drawn textbox in winforms.](https://web.archive.org/web/20131130031200/http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
richTextBoxConsole.GetPositionFromCharIndex(cursorPos)
```

Hide the normal caret and draw your own? Not tested, but should work I think.