# draw cursor on window

Tags: c#, winapi, caret

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Drawing a blinking caret in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848868/drawing-a-blinking-caret-in-winforms)

I write a text box, respectively for my needs, I use the winAPI function **drawtext** to draw the text that user types.
But when I reach the part of the drawing cursor (I do not mean the mouse cursor, but to the selection start cursor) I'm trying to understand how it should work, I see that in RichTextBox the text box do not redraw when you move the cursor. so how is the drawing of the cursor.

Comment: [Carets?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) See [Drawing a blinking caret in Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848868/drawing-a-blinking-caret-in-winforms).