# Windows forms: how to do a thick blinking cursor on a textbox?

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I am rewriting a windows forms application (updated framework, rewrote the logic, etc.) and there is one thing that I just can't figure out how they did.
Textboxes in the original application had a thick blinking cursor like so: http://screencast.com/t/8QYUcjuh3n

For the life of me I can't figure how to do this.  Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pinvoke [CreateCaret](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CreateCaret.html)

The example uses a Winform with a button (button1) and textbox (textBox1).

Add this using directive:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Add these declarations:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Add this code to the button click event:

```
  // Thickness is set where I have 10.
  CreateCaret(textBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 10, textBox1.Height);
  ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle);
```

When you click the button you'll get a thicker cursor.

There's also a discussion of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609927/custom-caret-for-winforms-textbox).

Comment: awesome thanks...now that I know what to search for I see how they invoked this.  Actually...this is a dailyWTF winner for sure

Comment: No problem.  Unfortunately for me my WTFs are more than daily!

Comment: Actually, I do have a problem with this, it seems like it causes the control handle and the form to be created on different threads.  form.Show() therefore causes a cross threading exception any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that would be.  I didn't see the problem when I tried the code but the example I constructed was very simple.

I wonder if you'd have more luck with the code linked below.  As you'll see, the class presented extends the TextBox by adding the same API calls but in a 'complete' solution. (I admit though I haven't tried the code in a real program).  

Can't create links in comments, so here it is separate:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d916db72-7744-44b7-ba66-7610927426ea?ppud=4

Good luck!