# Change Caret colour or hide it VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am making a program in VB.NET and need to hide the Caret in textboxes.

I could live with it being either completely hidden or just the same colour as the textboxes background colour. How can I go about doing this? I would prefer to stay away from Custom Controls if at all possible.

Thank you

Comment: WinForms, Silverlight or WPF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609927/custom-caret-for-winforms-textbox

Comment: @SLaks I have to make a game in VB.NET, and I am making the player able to control multiple characters. The easiest way to do this is to make each character a TextBox and then handle their KeyPress event. This way each player can move separately and they can be selected by TABing through them or clicking on them.

Comment: @ Daniel A. White WinForms. Sorry, I keep forgetting to specify that

Comment: You shouldn't use textboxes for that; you can handle `KeyPress` for any control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
Public Class NoCaretBox
  Inherits TextBox

  Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    HideCaret(Me.Handle)
    MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnLostFocus(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ShowCaret(Me.Handle)
    MyBase.OnLostFocus(e)
  End Sub

  Private Declare Function HideCaret Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
  Private Declare Function ShowCaret Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Class
```

Comment: As soon as I figured out the proper name for it was a Caret and not an I-Beam I found a solution on Google. It is pretty much the same as yours, so I'll give you the correct solution.

Comment: (I found it here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d7296516-0a00-405b-b9c8-f6f812c80cfc/)