# change caret color in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, caret

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Caret for WinForms TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609927/custom-caret-for-winforms-textbox)

I am trying to change the caret color in a richtextbox in winforms (c#), is there a way to do so?

I found articles about wpf, but nothing on winforms so far.

Comment: That could work, use a custom image to change caret color.

Comment: ended up using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting as it offers the custom carret and other functions I needed.