# How do I make it so that when the user goes into a textbox, the cursor color change C#

Tags: winforms, cursor

i have a small problem, i'm using winforms, i have a idea, i want change cursor color into textBox when the user is editing this it. The idea is show a color when user is writing, show a color no show a cursor.cur, How i can change the color cursor into texBox ?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you really want to change the `caret` (the vertical line that shows where the text cursor is), check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609927/custom-caret-for-winforms-textbox

Comment: I Solved the problem. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z1oZJjNPKFX_EyTCTxtKXkpSUctsGdhtrpUTJ8IrLM8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.  Provide an outline of the solution in your own words as well as the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change the cursor from one textbox in WinForms

1. Add the class NativeMethod

   ```
   public class NativeMethod {

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public extern static int GetCaretBlinkTime();
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public extern static int SetCaretBlinkTime(int wMSeconds);
   [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
   public extern static int GetCaretPos(ref POINT pt);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public extern static int SetCaretPos(int x, int y);
   [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
   public extern static int DestroyCaret();
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public extern static int CreateCaret(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public extern static int ShowCaret(IntPtr hwnd);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public extern static int HideCaret(IntPtr hwnd);

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   public struct POINT
   {
       public int x;
       public int y;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create the variables:

   ```
   private System.Drawing.Bitmap bm; private IntPtr hBitmap;
   ```
3. Add the Click and the TextChanged methods from TextBox  where the custom cursor will display, into these methods must add the following lines:

   ```
   NativeMethod.CreateCaret(this.textBox1.Handle, hBitmap, 0, 0);

   NativeMethod.ShowCaret(this.textBox1.Handle);
   ```
4. The respective methods will be as follows:

   ```
   private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       NativeMethod.CreateCaret(this.textBox1.Handle, hBitmap, 0, 0);
       NativeMethod.ShowCaret(this.textBox1.Handle);
   }
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       NativeMethod.CreateCaret(this.textBox1.Handle, hBitmap, 0, 0);
       NativeMethod.ShowCaret(this.textBox1.Handle);
   }
   ```
5. In the Form_Load event adding the next lines.

   ```
   bm = new Bitmap("puntero.png");
   hBitmap = bm.GetHbitmap();
   ```

Where "puntero.png" is a previously created image, the dimensions may vary, but in the example we using px size image 5X25 red, this image is in negative colors.