# Change Caret Size For RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change caret size for RichTextBox?

I want to change the `Width` of Caret.

Comment: You can change it.  But it will very quickly revert back, RTB resets it.  So there is no point.

Answer (score -1):

you may try this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCaret(richTextBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 10, richTextBox1.Font.Height);
        ShowCaret(richTextBox1.Handle);

    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609927/custom-caret-for-winforms-textbox)

Comment: abdullah, ive tried this but nothing happens ... caret width was still the same

Comment: @Elegiac , it should work now. bind the keyUp event and change caret size