# WinForms Set Richtextbox caret to "_"

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to change WinForms richtextbox's caret from "|" to "_"?
I tried finding some properties, what may change that, but i found only `rtb.Cursor` which sets cursor of mouse pointer, when it is over the control.

Comment: In insert mode this would be pretty silly imo; but in overwrite some kind of blockcursor should be used automatically. Here it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two examples:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/63019/Custom-Caret-for-WinForms-richtextbox
- [Change Caret Size For RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593085/change-caret-size-for-richtextbox)

However they both involve using DLLIMPORT to get and overwrite some old, unmanaged functions of Windows. Not exactly a trivial and trouble free operation. Be certain you really need this.

Of course as for many problem cases from Windows Forms, this stuff is usally pretty easy to do in [WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox)/UWP.