# How do you create Multi-Carets in a TextBox C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, caret

I find many professional text editors like Sublime Text and Synwrite that has a feature as a Multi-Caret editor. The text caret will actually insert to different lines inside the editor so you can actually edit multiple lines for the same type of code. So there's no need for copy paste anymore.

[image: Here is a GIF image of Cuda Text editor with the Multi Caret feature.]

So can anyone help to achieve this in C#?

Comment: You will have to use [winapi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648398(v=vs.85).aspx) here, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610057/1997232). Another option is custom control, where you can draw with gdi+ whatever you want (blinking is .. kek).